# Use react components in html as html tags

Tags: html, reactjs, web-component

I have a simple react component defined as follows

```js
var MyComp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>This is a new component</div>
    );
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
```

I want to be able to use this component in html by simply typing `<MyComp></MyComp>` instead of using `React.render();` Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this does it - https://github.com/PixelsCommander/ReactiveElements perfectly well

Comment: i don't know what to do, the repo don't tell what link to include can you tell me what file to download?